# Linux, GNU GCC, ld, version scripts and the ELF binary format -- How does it work?

Tags: linux, gcc, ld

I'm trying to learn more about library versioning in Linux and how to put it all to work. Here's the context:

-- I have two versions of a dynamic library which expose the same set of interfaces, say `libsome1.so` and `libsome2.so`.

-- An application is linked against `libsome1.so`.

-- This application uses `libdl.so` to dynamically load another module, say `libmagic.so`.

-- Now `libmagic.so` is linked against `libsome2.so`. Obviously, without using linker scripts to hide symbols in `libmagic.so`, at run-time all calls to interfaces in `libsome2.so` are resolved to `libsome1.so`. This can be confirmed by checking the value returned by `libVersion()` against the value of the macro `LIB_VERSION`.

-- So I try next to compile and link `libmagic.so` with a linker script which hides all symbols except 3 which are defined in `libmagic.so` and are exported by it. This works... Or at least `libVersion()` and `LIB_VERSION` values match (and it reports version 2 not 1).

-- However, when some data structures are serialized to disk, I noticed some corruption. In the application's directory if I delete `libsome1.so` and create a soft link in its place to point to `libsome2.so`, everything works as expected and the same corruption does not happen.

I can't help but think that this may be caused due to some conflict in the run-time linker's resolution of symbols. I've tried many things, like trying to link `libsome2.so` so that all symbols are alised to `symbol@@VER_2` (which I am still confused about because the command `nm -CD libsome2.so` still lists symbols as `symbol` and not `symbol@@VER_2`)... Nothing seems to work!!! Help!!!!!!

Edit: I should have mentioned it earlier, but the app in question is Firefox, and `libsome1.so` is `libsqlite3.so` shipped with it. I don't quite have the option of recompiling them. Also, using version scripts to hide symbols seems to be the only solution right now. So what really happens when symbols are hidden? Do they become 'local' to the SO? Does rtld have no knowledge of their existence? What happens when an exported function refers to a hidden symbol?

Comment: Have you tried at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @joksnet: I thought stackexchange was for users and not developers... This question is related to development in C++ Linux... Or am I just deluded? :) Edit: I am wrong!!! For some reason I thought stackexchange = serverfault!! I wasn't aware of unix.stackexchange.com!!

Comment: Yes! Because it's still on beta, and has not it own domain.

Comment: Awrite... posted the same question of unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @themoondothshine please avoid cross posting your questions to every Stack Exchange with a technical audience. You had it right the first time, but if you didn't, the community would've taken care of getting it to the right place.

Comment: @joksnet I fail to see how a question about the technical aspects of linking isn't on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Mark: Sorry about that... My mistake... I did follow @joksnet's advise though...

Comment: I agree with Mark. I've added a bounty on to see if we can get a decent explanation.

Comment: Related background information on so numbers: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475/how-do-so-shared-object-numbers-work from my own question.

Comment: @ninefingers: Your question very precisely describes what I'm so intrigued about! I've actually decided now to go back to absolute basics... Beginning with the ELF format!!!!!!! Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 3):

Try compiling both `libsome1.so` and `libsome2.so` to add symbol versioning, each with their own version (use the `--version-script` option to `ld`). Then link the application and `libmagic.so` using the new libraries. Then, `libsome1.so` and `libsome2.so` should be completely separate.

Problems can still occur if there are unversioned references to symbols. Such references can be satisfied by versioned definitions (so that it is possible to add symbol versioning to a library without breaking binary compatibility). If there are multiple symbols of the same name, it can sometimes be hard to predict which one will be used.

Regarding tools, `nm -D` does not display any information about symbol versioning. Try `objdump -T` or `readelf -s` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I did learn something new! I probably should've mentioned it earlier, but the app in question is Firefox and `libsome1.so` is `libsqlite3.so` shipped with it. So there's no way I have the option of recompiling them. However I did try your solution on minimalist sample I had created to model the situation... And it worked!

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty. I think this is well deserved; your answer is good. Have some more rep!