# Linux, GNU GCC, ld, version scripts and the ELF binary format -- How does it work?

Tags: linux, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux, GNU GCC, ld, version scripts and the ELF binary format — How does it work??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660388/linux-gnu-gcc-ld-version-scripts-and-the-elf-binary-format-how-does-it-work)

I'm trying to learn more about library versioning in Linux and how to put it all to work. Here's the context:

I have two versions of a dynamic library which expose the same set of interfaces, say `libsome1.so` and `libsome2.so`. An application is linked against `libsome1.so`.

This application uses `libdl.so` to dynamically load another module, say `libmagic.so`. Now `libmagic.so` is linked against `libsome2.so`. Obviously, without using linker scripts to hide symbols in `libmagic.so`, at run-time all calls to interfaces in `libsome2.so` are resolved to `libsome1.so`. This can be confirmed by checking the value returned by `libVersion()` against the value of the macro `LIB_VERSION`.

So I try next to compile and link `libmagic.so` with a linker script which hides all symbols except 3 which are defined in `libmagic.so` and are exported by it. This works... Or at least `libVersion()` and `LIB_VERSION` values match (and it reports version 2 not 1).

However, when some data structures are serialized to disk, I noticed some corruption. In the application's directory if I delete `libsome1.so` and create a soft link in its place to point to `libsome2.so`, everything works as expected and the same corruption does not happen.

I can't help but think that this may be caused due to some conflict in the run-time linker's resolution of symbols. I've tried many things, like trying to link `libsome2.so` so that all symbols are alised to `symbol@@VER_2` (which I am still confused about because the command `nm -CD libsome2.so` still lists symbols as `symbol` and not `symbol@@VER_2`), but nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?